# If $f :\colon A \rightarrow B$, then $f^{-1}(B) = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f\colon A \rightarrow B$. Prove the following statement: $f^{-1}(B) = A$.

My attempts:

$f^{-1}(B) = \{a\in A\mid f(a)\in B\}$ is a subset of $A$.

But I can't prove the other way, i.e. $A$ is the subset of $f^{-1}(B)$. I have no idea about it.

Comment: Check out the section about using LaTeX on Math.SE on [this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 3):

Pick $a\in A$. $f(a)\in B$. *By definition* of $f^{-1}(B)$, $a\in f^{-1}(B)$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for what elements $a\in A$ can $f(a)\in B$ (that is, $a\in f^{-1}(B)$) fail?

Comment: none? I think for all a ∈ A, f(a) also ∈B. Am I correct?

Comment: @user126430 Yes, you're correct. So…

Comment: So can I just write the proof in the following way:
f −1 (B) = {all a belongs to A such that f(a) belongs to B} = {all a belongs to A} = A

Comment: Oh i think i can figure out the other way now. I understand your hint now. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$Here is the proof from a comment of yours, but now reasoning at the logic level.

For every $\;a\;$,
$$\calc
a \in f^{-1}[B]
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$}
\langle \exists b : f^{-1}(b) = a : b \in B \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\cdot^{-1}\;$}
\langle \exists b : f(a) = b : b \in B \rangle
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: one-point rule}
f(a) \in B
\calcop{\equiv}{using the fact that$\;f : A \to B\;$}
a \in A
\endcalc$$
By set extensionality, $\;f^{-1}[B] = A\;$.

Note how this proof separately uses the properties of $\;\cdot[\cdot]\;$ and $\;\cdot^{-1}\;$ in the first three steps.  Usually these would be merged as one step, with a comment like $"\text{definition of $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$}"$.